# Authentication And Login Page - how do I authenticate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I was reading: [FormsAuthentication with Razor not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099351/formsauthentication-with-razor-not-working) but could got a few errors from the response.

```
using  System.Web.Security;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model, string name, string pw)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.ValidateUser(name, pw))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pw) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            try 
            {
                var db = new UsersDBContext();
                var Name = (from Users in db.Users
                            where Users.Name == name && Users.Password == pw
                            select Users.CustomerId).Single();

                if (Name != 0)
                {
                    string myIDString = Name.ToString();
                    Session["myID"] = myIDString;
                    return Redirect("/LogModels/Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
                var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                        .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

                // Join the list to a single string.
                var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

                // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
                var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

                // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
                throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Add alert -> password does not exist/is wrong etc.
        }
    }
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

The problem is when I try to add the

```
&& Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)
```

I'm getting following error.

> Membership does not exist in the current context

I'm rather new to this so please explain in a very simple way if possible.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

LoginModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebPortalMVC.Models
{
    [Table("Users")]
    public class UsersModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        /*
        [Display(Name = "Remember me on this computer")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        */
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    }  
    public class UsersDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersDBContext() : base("MySqlConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UsersModel> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View (not all of it)

```
<div id="login">
                <h1>Web Portal</h1>

                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <p>
                        @Html.TextBox("name", "", new { type = "email", placeholder = "example@email.com" })
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Html.Password("pw",  "", new { type = "password", placeholder = "Password" })
                    </p>
                        <input type="submit" id="loginsubmit" value="Log in" onclick="emptypasswordcheck()" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

**EDIT 2: ** Added code according to @FreshBM answer.

Comment: Show your model and view code as well.

Comment: @AmneshGoel added now :)

Comment: @freshbm I was actually using System.Web already :/

Comment: @DanAndersson add `System.Web.Security` and test it again .. see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Did that @AmneshGoel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Membership.ValidateUser` is located in [System.Web.Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-%20us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser(v=vs.100).aspx) namespace. So judging by your error message that you get I presume that you don't have reference to System.Web.Security.

Try adding it.

Edit:

Also you need to change your call to ValidateUser, because you don't have model as parameter in your Index action. Instead you have two params, name and pwd:

```
Membership.ValidateUser(name, pwd)
```

or if you want to use LoginModel add using directive:

```
using WebPortalMVC.Models;
```

Tip: Maybe the easiest way to relove problems with missing using directives is to right click on class name and use `Resolve` from context menu or you can use keyboard shortcut: `Ctrl + .`

You can refer to this tutorials for configuring membership provider in MVC:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

and

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18813/Using-Forms-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.htm

Comment: This did indeed fix that problem. Now I get the error: 

    The name "model" does not exist in the current context.    

So then I tried to add "LoginModel model" in the Actionresult Index which then resulted in "The type or namespace name 'LoginModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Ok, that is the other problem. But you don't have model in your action, you have string name and string pwd so you need to change Membership.ValidateUser call. I will update answer...

Comment: Great! Now there seems to be the problem that when I try to log in it waits forever and says that it can't connect to the database after a while. I assume it's a problem with the Membership.ValidateUser(name, pw) part. How does it work exactly. Where does it check the name and pw? Do I have to make a Membership list somewhere? Or does it go into my database directly somehow?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code:

Additional information: Could not connect to the SQL-Database.  - But when I go back to if (ModelState.IsValid) only - it still works.

Comment: Ok, that is another problem: you didn't configure your application to use membership for authentication in your app. Here you have two turorials that explains in details how to configure membership provider: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18813/Using-Forms-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.htm and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF. So you can follow them, but that was not your original question, so if you are satisfied with answer feel free to accept it.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as an answer and post another thread if I get any problems after reading those guides. Thanks for all your help :)